# Don't know why my background isn't covering all the content

Tags: html, css, formatting

I am a IT student and have been trying to build a website as part of my assignment. I current have an issue with my background which is not auto adjusting correctly to the content put in place. On one page it include all the sub-divs but not on another.

```css
.mainContent {
    font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    padding: 30px 30px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContent">
    <h1>Featured Artist - Monarchy</h1>
    <h4 class="fontChange">Artist Biography:</h4>
    <p class="fontChange">
        Monarchy are a British rock band made up of Fred Venus, Bryan June, 
        Roger Cobbler and Jon Vicars. They formed in Preston in 1970 after 
        Bryan & Roger left their previous band 'Cheesy Grin'. They achieved 
        moderate chart success and have played to large stadiums such as 
        the Globe Arena, Deepdale Stadium & Gigg Lane. Their first album 
        'Monarchy' reached a high point of 164 in the album charts in 1974, 
        while their 1075 album 'Night at the Guilhall' brought them international 
        success and was the top selling album that year in Liechtenstein.
        That album featured the single 'Slavic Symphony', which stayed at 
        number one in the UK for nine seconds.
    </p>
    <h5 class="fontChange">
        Albums
    </h5>
    <div id="albumOne">
        <img class="imgBorder" src="Assets/Images/monarchy-album.jpg">
        </img>
        <span class="caption">Text below the image</span>
    </div>
    <div id="albumTwo">
        <img class="imgBorder" src="Assets/Images/monarchy-DE.jpg">
        </img>
        <span class="caption">Text below the image</span>
    </div>
    <div id="albumThree">
        <img class="imgBorder" src="Assets/Images/monarchy-ES.jpg">
        </img>
        <span class="caption">Text below the image</span>
    </div>
    <div id="albumFour">
        <img class="imgBorder" src="Assets/Images/monarchy-ludo.jpg">
        </img>
        <span class="caption">Text below the image</span>
    </div>
    <div id="albumFive">
        <img class="imgBorder" src="Assets/Images/monarchy-album.jpg">
        </img>
        <span class="caption">Text below the image</span>
    </div>
    <div id="albumSix">
        <img class="imgBorder" src="Assets/Images/monarchy-DE.jpg">
        </img>
        <span class="caption">Text below the image</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The grey background should include the subsequent divs.

I appologise for the poor formatting, this is my first post.

Example of it working on the first page

[image]

Example of it not working on the second

[image]

Comment: Can you add more details? Images are not sufficient to understand the problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

It's because html body has margin:8px in default.
So you should set the body margin to 0px

```css
  html body {
    margin: 0;
  }
 .mainContent {
    font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    height: auto;
    width:100%
}
.title{
margin-top:0px
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContent">
    <h1 class="title">Featured Artist - Monarchy</h1>
    <h4 class="fontChange">Artist Biography:</h4>
    <p class="fontChange">
        Monarchy are a British rock band made up of Fred Venus, Bryan June, 
        Roger Cobbler and Jon Vicars. They formed in Preston in 1970 after 
        Bryan & Roger left their previous band 'Cheesy Grin'. They achieved 
        moderate chart success and have played to large stadiums such as 
        the Globe Arena, Deepdale Stadium & Gigg Lane. Their first album 
        'Monarchy' reached a high point of 164 in the album charts in 1974, 
        while their 1075 album 'Night at the Guilhall' brought them international 
        success and was the top selling album that year in Liechtenstein.
        That album featured the single 'Slavic Symphony', which stayed at 
        number one in the UK for nine seconds.
    </p>
    <h5 class="fontChange">
        Albums
    </h5>
    <div id="albumOne">
        <img class="imgBorder" src="Assets/Images/monarchy-album.jpg">
        </img>
        <span class="caption">Text below the image</span>
    </div>
    <div id="albumTwo">
        <img class="imgBorder" src="Assets/Images/monarchy-DE.jpg">
        </img>
        <span class="caption">Text below the image</span>
    </div>
    <div id="albumThree">
        <img class="imgBorder" src="Assets/Images/monarchy-ES.jpg">
        </img>
        <span class="caption">Text below the image</span>
    </div>
    <div id="albumFour">
        <img class="imgBorder" src="Assets/Images/monarchy-ludo.jpg">
        </img>
        <span class="caption">Text below the image</span>
    </div>
    <div id="albumFive">
        <img class="imgBorder" src="Assets/Images/monarchy-album.jpg">
        </img>
        <span class="caption">Text below the image</span>
    </div>
    <div id="albumSix">
        <img class="imgBorder" src="Assets/Images/monarchy-DE.jpg">
        </img>
        <span class="caption">Text below the image</span>
    </div>
</div>
```